# How to convey in Spanish "That is flattering" with positive connotations?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sinónimos

I'm trying to translate into Spanish something as simple as

> That is **flattering**

To respond to or to describe something someone does or says to you,  with the connotations and context of:

- What you said or did highlights something genuinely good about me
- What you said or did was sincere. It was not just said or done to please me or to get something from me
- What you said or did made me feel good or valued
- I appreciate your feedback/comment/action

For example:

> You took a long time to research and look for a gift for me. It is *flattering* that somebody thinks that one is worth all that time and effort.
>
> That compliment was *flattering*. No BS, no "kissing your butt", just plain and sincere "you did something that was good", and that was very rewarding and satisfying.
>
> The way you look at me is really *flattering*. Makes me think I'm the only girl in the world. Makes me think there's something especial and unique about me.

First thing that comes to my mind would be "[adulador](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0r2tUGI)", but the DRAE's definition gives this term a connotation of "unsincere" and plain "sweet-talker", even "servile", rather than truly admiring, appreciative and complimentary

> 1. tr. Hacer o decir con intención, a veces inmoderadamente, lo que se cree que puede agradar a otro.

Similarli, "lisonjero" or "[lisonjear](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NQ88Wmk)", which is a sinonim of "adular" is described as

> 2. tr. Dar motivo de envanecimiento.

I wish that there was a term that would not involve "please or feed someone's vanity, maybe with a second intention".

What could be a good translation for "flattering" in Spanish that conveys only positive connotations about the compliment itself, especially considering that the compliment might even be unintentional.

Comment: Halagüeño/halagador?

Comment: @ukemi Pues es una buena opción (ponlo como posible respuesta si quieres). Viendo la [entrada del RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JyT2gRw), la primera acepción sí puede ser lo que busco, la segunda evidentemente no. Y es lo que me llama la atención de muchos de estos términos, que están cargados de connotaciones negativas. Quizá sea porque siempre se puede dar este uso con dobles intenciones cuando hacer un halago, adulas, lisonjeas... por eso de ahí la pregunta, a ver si aparte de todos estos hay alguno que no deje casi lugar a dudas.

Comment: Qué tal simplemente *(eso) me agrada*, ya que la raíz comparte origen tanto con *grato* como con *gracias*.

Comment: We need a sample sentence and context, please.  By the way, what I'm used to hearing is "Thank you for those kind words" or "That was such a thoughtful gift."  The most common way I hear "flattering" is "Blue is such a flattering color for you."

Comment: In Spanish we'd use the sentence: "Es un halago."

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  The three examples given are pretty different.  "Flattering" has multiple meanings and uses.  The translation may be different depending on which meaning and use you're focusing on.  I think it's okay to cite multiple examples, but a well-posed question would narrow things down to your top priority.  And although a sample sentence is apparently not required here, it sure would help folks help you.

Comment: @aparente001 Isn't this the second time that you VTC this question? You VTCed already, arguing that [there aren't any sample sentences with a blank where the word would go](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3084/5481) and the community voted to keep the question open. Now you vote again with a different reason. I'm not sure if the community is going to act differently, if they didn't find reasons to close it the first time. Also, provide some feedback please. Why do you claim those examples are different? they all explain a situation in which someone says "what you did was flattering".

Comment: @Diego - *becoming, kind, effective, enhancing, ingratiating, complimentary, gratifying, fawning, pleasing, satisfying, gratifying, pleasurable.*  "Flattering" covers, according to Collins, three *different* meanings.  Please don't take it personally -- I think the question needs narrowing down.

Comment: @aparente001 Es que esa es la gracia de la pregunta. Buscar en español si hay un término que cubra "kind, ingratiating, complimentary, gratifying, fawning, pleasing, satisfying, pleasurable" (mira mi explicación del contexto) con connotaciones solo positivas. De lo contrario, podría responderse directametne con una búsqueda en un diccionario Inglés-Español. The questions is: if you had to translate the question's examples into Spanish, what word would you pick for "flattering" or how would you convey it?

Comment: Okay, rereading the question, it looks like you're excluding *fawning*, at least.  I guess that's a partial narrowing. // To me, trying to find *one* word to map three different meanings onto feels like trying to get a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: I pasted the question in google translate and the first answer was "halagador" which i think is the best correct answer and usage in a good context, in a bad context we can use adulador

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb ***[halagar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JyT2gRw)*** and its derived adjective ***[halagador](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JySd0nS)*** and substantive ***[halago](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JyUEAps)*** are useful in this context:

> *Vaya, eso es muy halagador por tu parte, ¡gracias!*

If you want a single word for this, I think these are your safest bet if you want others to know that you actually mean it — at least compared to the ones you mentioned: *adular*, *lisonjear*. Note that it works better if you add *muy*, *mucho* or some other intensive before it.

You can also use ***[agradar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=17iDZMe)*** as an auxiliar verb:

> *Vaya, me agrada oír eso, ¡gracias!*

Though I don't feel it has the same intensity as "flattering".

Finally, if you are OK with using idioms, I would say that the most common way of expressing "being extremely flattered" in (European) Spanish is [***ponerse colorado***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TdpEAZG#EAGUv3K) (or *ponerse rojo*):

> *Vaya, me voy a poner colorado, ¡gracias!*

This literally means "to turn red". And now that I think of it, it has its own verb too, [***ruborizar***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WmyIygJ):

> *Vaya, me voy a ruborizar, ¡gracias!*

Your examples translated using each of the options:

> It is flattering that somebody thinks that [...]
>   *Me halaga que alguien piense que [...]
>
>   Es muy halagador que alguien piense que [...]
>
>   Es todo un halago que alguien piense que [...]
>
>   Me agrada mucho que alguien piense que [...]
>
>   Me pone colorado que alguien piense que [...]
>
>   Me ruboriza que alguien piense que [...]*
>
> That compliment was flattering.
>   *Ese cumplido me halagó mucho.
>   Ese cumplido fue todo un halago.
>
>   Ese cumplido fue muy halagador.
>
>   Ese cumplido me agradó mucho.
>
>   Ese cumplido me hizo ponerme colorado.
>
>   Ese cumplido me hizo ruborizarme.*
>
> The way you look at me is really flattering.
>   *La forma en que me miras es realmente halagadora.
>
>   La forma en que me miras realmente me halaga.
>
>   La forma en que me miras me agrada realmente.
>
>   La forma en que me miras me hace ponerme colorado.
>
>   La forma en que me miras me hace ruborizarme.*